# Excel Function to find the closest value to a distinct string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
fall    rise    na  fall    na  fall    fall    rise    na  fall    rise    rise    peak    fall    rise    na  fall    fall    rise    na  na  fall    na  fall
```

I need to find the word 'na' that is closest and left of the word 'peak'.

Comment: are the values in different cells or all in the same cell?

Comment: sorry, A1 would be hour 0, and A2 would be fall

Comment: So I assume your expected outcome would be 8 in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution that provides the same results as Scott's answer:

```
=INDEX(A1:X1,1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((OFFSET(A2,0,0,1,MATCH("peak",A2:X2,0))="na")*COLUMN(OFFSET(A2,0,0,1,MATCH("peak",A2:X2,0))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$X$1,LARGE(IF((COLUMN(A2:$X$2)<MATCH("peak",$A$2:$X$2,0))*($A$2:$X$2="na"),COLUMN(A2:$X$2)),1))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or

You can use this normal formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$X$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A2:$X$2)/((COLUMN(A2:$X$2)<MATCH("peak",$A$2:$X$2,0))*($A$2:$X$2="na")),1))
```

[image]

Comment: You're getting too fast on these AGGREGATE/INDEX pairs. `=INDEX(1:1, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A:X)/(A2:INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH("peak",2:2, 0)-1)="na"), 1))`

Comment: Jeeped, I like the denominator logic.  It makes sense.  It only iterates over those that it needs to.